# not printing reverse element using function

Tags: c++, function, vector, reverse

whenever I am trying to make a display function `void display(vector<int> ivec)`
It should print me the reversed vector elements after implementing the reverse function but it's not , but when I am trying to print to the elements inside my reverse function it is printing me the reversed elements why so ?

Code:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

void reversefun(vector<int>ivec, int start, int end){
  while(start < end){ // 
    int temp= ivec[start];
    ivec[start] = ivec[end];
    ivec[end] = temp; 
    start++;
    end--;
  }
     
}

void display(vector<int> ivec){
  for(int i = 0; i <ivec.size(); i ++){
    cout<< ivec[i] << " " ;
  }
}
  
int main(){
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  vector<int> ivec(n);

  for(auto &i: ivec){
    cin>>i;
  }
  int start = 0;
  int end = ivec.size();
  reversefun(ivec,start,end-1);
  display(ivec);
  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:-

```
5 
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Expected Output:-

```
5
1 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: you pass the vector by value. `reversefun` modifies a copy of the vector.

Comment: you could (/should) use [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) to reverse elements of a vector

Comment: Well, Any idea how to fix it? I want to implement display function to print my reversed vector elements instead writing it on reversefun

Comment: Well I don't want to use std::reverse I want to reverse it using like this

Comment: pass it by reference `void reversefun(vector<int>& ivec, int start, int end)` and `display` should be `void display(const vector<int>& ivec)`

Comment: Thank you, can you explain me why we have used const in display function?

Comment: you cannot reverse it "like this" because your function does not reverse the vector. Even when you want to practice you can look at how the standard way works and cppreference often has a possible implementation you can try to understand and learn from